# Android 7.1 Screen Orientation Issues

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, landscape

Hi our "landscape mode" game works fine on anything below Android 7.1 including Android 7.0. However, on a phone such as the Google Pixel XL (Android 7.1) it will not load properly if the device is in the portrait mode position and then rotated to landscape mode. Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image: Google Pixel XL Screen Issue]

Our current android manifest contains the following:

```
 android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Any advice to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to support both orientations or just landscape? I don't think cocos2d-x supports it out of the box.

Comment: Just landscape, but player should be able to use either "landscape" or "reverse landscape"

Comment: There's a problem with "onSizeChanged" method. Check this out: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/resolution-problem-while-launching-game-through-push-notification-from-lock-screen/22254/2

Comment: @Makalele thank you, the solution from that discussion fixed the issue with Android 7.1. We also mentioned this solution on the cocos2d-x GitHub project.